# comparing the same table over two rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

So this is what i have

```
Table : Bill
+------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| id   | patient_id | bill_number     | confirmed_date      |
+------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|   14 |         32 | 4657            | 2012-07-06 04:11:05 |
|   15 |         33 | 4567            | 2012-07-07 05:11:05 |
|   16 |         34 | 4568            | 2012-07-08 06:11:05 |
|   17 |         35 | 7445            | 2012-08-08 07:11:05 |
+------+------------+-----------------+---------------------+

Table: Claim
+------+---------+------------+-------+--------------+---------------------+
```

| id   | bill_id | patient_id | level | claim_format | confirmed_date      |
+------+---------+------------+-------+--------------+---------------------+
|   10 |      14 |         32 |     1 | 1500         | 2012-08-10 10:57:17 |
|   11 |      14 |         32 |     1 | UB04         | 2012-08-10 11:01:42 |
|   12 |      15 |         33 |     1 | 1500         | 2012-09-10 13:57:17 |
|   13 |      15 |         33 |     1 | UB04         | 2012-09-10 12:01:42 |
|   14 |      16 |         34 |     1 | 1500         | 2012-10-10 12:57:17 |
|   15 |      16 |         34 |     1 | UB04         | 2012-10-10 13:01:42 |
|   16 |      17 |         35 |     1 | 1500         | 0012-11-10 15:57:17 |
|   17 |      17 |         35 |     1 | UB04         | 2012-11-10 14:01:42 |
+------+---------+------------+-------+--------------+---------------------+

I want to update the confirmed_date column of bill table with the confirmed_date of claim table after comparing the greater of the two dates for each bill_id(bill_id and patient_id in claims are foreign keys to id and patient_id in bill)

Did i make myself clear enough?

Comment: Do you mean update bill.confirmed_date with the most_recent confirmed_date from the Claim table for a particular bill_id?

Comment: yes, you can say that

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Bill b
SET b.confirmed_date = ( SELECT MAX(confirmed_date) FROM Claim c WHERE b.id = c.bill_id)
```

Comment: This does not compare the dates and figure out which one is greater. It might work for this sample data but if i tweak the dates a bit here and there it fails.

Comment: what are the dates you want to compare? claim.confirmed_date for a particular bill_id or bill.comfirmed_date with claim.confirmed_date? Maybe, posting the expected bill table for the example you have given might help

Comment: i want to compare the claim.confirmed_date for the same bill_id and pick up the greater one and update the bill table with it for the corresponding bill.